# Android Go - Widget Support

Tags: app-widgets, android-go

I currently have a Samsung M01 Core running on Android 10 Go Edition. The installed launcher is One UI Home.

This launcher have some predefined widgets but an important one is missing: a clock. Since it's a Go edition phone, Android Widgets downloaded from the Play Store won't work out of the box and you need a custom launcher to use those.

The issue is that custom launchers do not have access to the notification list (the option is missing from the Accessibility settings since it is not supported) therefore they can't display the notification count next to apps which is also critical for me.

Is it possible to somehow force a simple widget (a clock) to appear within the default list of widgets in One UI? If not, is there another solution (maybe enabling notification access) that I can look into?